# Importing data from a text file into an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to import these data file values in an array.
so times[0] would be 23,8 etc...

Example data file web.txt (temperature values in C°):

```
23,8
23,2
22,8
22,0
... etc
```

The code below is what i have thusfar reading the web.txt
file and displaying the values in a browser.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>load demo</title>
  <style>
  body {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p id="myid"></p>
<script>
var times = [];

 $.get('web.txt', function(data) {
        //var fileDom = $(data);

        var lines = data.split("\n");
        $.each(lines, function(n, elem) {
            $('#myid').append('<div>' + elem + '</div>');
        });
    });


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you already have the array in `lines`. Why do you need 2 arrays?

Comment: i didnt realise that lines was also an array

Comment: well that doesn't really make sense or you wouldn't have created an `each` loop of `lines`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works.

Just rename

```
var lines = data.split("\n");
$.each(lines, function(n, elem) ...
```

to

```
times = data.split("\n");
$.each(times, function(n, elem) ...
```

Comment: `var times` should `times`, because it has previously been declared.